# PHP: Can't display simple addition

Tags: php

Basically I'm trying to add 3 numbers together by storing them as variables then adding them up 3+4+5 and it's coming back as 312? No clue why.. code is below:

```
<?php
    echo"
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                ".date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')."
            </td>
            <td>
                 ".
                $N1 = 3;
                $N2 = 4;
                $N3 = 5;
                $sum_total = $N1 + $N2 + $N3;

                print ("$sum_total") ."

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is being evaluated in context of **string concatenation**:

```
$N1 = 3;
$N2 = 4;
$N3 = 5;
$sum_total = $N1 + $N2 + $N3;

print ("$sum_total")
```

you should calculate a value and concatenate it (without `print`ing it.):

```
$sum_total = ...;

echo"
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            ".date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')."
        </td>
        <td>
             ${sum_total}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>";
```

Here both expansion (see `${sum_total}` inside a string) and concatenation (for date) are used.

Answer (score 1):

You're assinging values whilst in the middle of echo'ing out a string.
What you should do is do the variable assignment outside the echo.

```
<?php

$N1 = 3;
$N2 = 4;
$N3 = 5;
$sum_total = $N1 + $N2 + $N3;
echo"
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            ".date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')."
        </td>
        <td>
             " . $sum_total . "
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Why would it error? `$N1` becomes `3`, it gets printed, `3 + 4 + 5` evaluate to `12`, that gets printed too. No big mystery.

Comment: It just seems like an odd construction to me that should have thrown some kind of error. But hey, It's PHP...

Comment: Doubtless not what OP expected, but it's grammatical.

Comment: The value of an assignment expression is the value assigned. That is, the value of "$a = 3" is 3. This allows you to do some tricky things:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: I've removed my assumption it would have to error. Thanks for pointing this out. I've learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>
               <?php echo  date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php
                $N1 = 3;
                $N2 = 4;
                $N3 = 5;
                $sum_total = $N1 + $N2 + $N3;

                print ($sum_total);
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` — Output a string and not need the parenthesis.

Try with -

```
$N1 = 3;
$N2 = 4;
$N3 = 5;
$sum_total = $N1 + $N2 + $N3;
echo"
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            ".date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')."
        </td>
        <td>
             ".$sum_total ."
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>";
```

Comment: Let’s cast just assigned integer to integer! It always helps.

Comment: Why are casting an int to an int?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<?php
    echo "
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                ".date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')."
            </td>
            <td>";


                $N1 = 3;
                $N2 = 4;
                $N3 = 5;
                $sum_total = $N1 + $N2 + $N3;

                print ($sum_total);

          echo "  </td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
?>
```